# Linked List: Smart Pointer Implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

Linked list using smart pointers, iterative implementation. It amazes me how a `std::forward_list` does not allow the list to be walked until the last pointer is `null`.

I would appreciate if you could pay special attention to usage of `shared_ptr`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cmath>

const int SIZE=7;

struct Node {
    int val;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
};
std::shared_ptr<Node> newNode(int v) { // Create and return new node
    std::shared_ptr<Node> n(new Node);
    n->val = v;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}
void print(std::shared_ptr<Node> r) { // Print the list
    while (r != NULL) {
        std::cout << r->val << ' ';
        r = r->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> root(new Node), last;
    srand(time(NULL));
    root->val = rand();
    root->next = NULL;
    last = root;
    for (int i=1; i<SIZE; ++i) { // Build the list
        last->next = newNode(rand());
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = NULL; 
    print(root); 
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not rather using a `std::list<std::shared_ptr<int>>` instead?

Comment: ..or just a ``std::forward_list``, right :D? The point is to recreate a classic linked list, which can be walked until the ``next`` pointer is NULL. Oddly, this is not possible with std::forward_list.

Comment: I added the "reinventing the wheel" tag which is intended for implementing something that already exists for challenge/learning purposes. Hope you get great answers!

Comment: Astounding to me is that a ``std::forward_list`` cannot be walked until the ``next`` pointer is ``NULL``. That was a classic question! Also, they LOVE to ask linked list questions on interviews, and swooping a problem with a library function won't impress the hiring manager.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "Astounding to me is that a std::forward_list cannot be walked until the next pointer is NULL"? Isn't that exactly what's expressed by `for (auto&& elem : myfwdlist)`?

Comment: Note that in your code snippet you haven't implemented a *list*, just a *list node*. You don't yet have any abstraction equivalent to `std::forward_list<T>`; all you have is pointers to individual nodes.

Comment: If the hiring manager isn't impressed that you are able to leverage the standard libraries when solving a problem, then they are a clueless idiot who doesn't know how to evaluate the skill of a programmer. You probably don't want to work there.

Comment: @CodyGray, it's not that simple. Let's say they ask you the classic, "How do you reverse a string?" Well ``std::reverse`` is the easy answer, but that doesn't say anything about your skill level in string manipulation, problem solving, analytic thinking, performance trade-offs, C-string vs ``std::string``, etc. Yes, a candidate needs to be aware of such library functions, but this answer alone is not going to get you the job.

Comment: Yes, that would show that you know (A) how to reverse a string (as asked), (B) how to use the standard library to solve problems, and (C) you use the appropriate tools for the job. If a candidate wrote a `for` loop, that'd be a major red flag for me. Programmers should not have a "skill level" in "string manipulation". Writing your own string handling code is what leads to major security vulnerabilities. There's no analytic thinking demonstrated by that problem, and there's no more performant way to do it than the standard algorithms. Maybe that just means these stock interview questions suck.

Comment: @CodyGray, I see your point, but the key is to give the interviewer what they want. **You** would be happy with the ``std::reverse`` answer, but another interviewer might want to see a candidate's skill with C-strings, because they're stuck with maintaining old code. My strategy is to say something like, "Well, the easiest way to reverse a string is to use ``std::reverse``, but techniques vary across C, C++, and different libraries. Which approach should I take?"

Comment: Furthermore, yes, there is analytic thinking demonstrated by the problem: what is the optimal way to reverse a string--and **not** using std::reverse? Along the same lines, how do you reverse a linked list, **not** using the .reverse() method? This demonstrates understanding of pointers, data structures, nodes, etc.

Comment: The analytic thinking there is essentially limited to, "Wait, I thought I was interviewing for a C++ job! Why do they want me to write C?" Even if you are maintaining old code, you don't reinvent standard algorithms. Which brings me back to my original point: a hiring manager that wants to see this is a clueless idiot. Sorry, I just think this is such nonsense. I don't mean to pick on you. It's great that you want to learn how to do it the unsafe way, and you're probably more likely to get hired than I am.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52368/discussion-between-kmiklas-and-cody-gray).

Answer (score 3):

> I would appreciate if you could pay special attention to usage of shared_ptr.

This fills me with dread. It implies that you want every node to have shared ownership. My question would be, "shared with what? another list?".

`shared_ptr` contains code for thread-safe reference counting. For this reason, use of a `shared_ptr` in a single-threaded program brings with it an unnecessary overhead.

There may be some use cases for sharing nodes - for example in a directed graph structure. In this case, almost any other container for holding node pointers would be superior to a linked list.

Before I can continue the review, I'd have to ask what the intended use-case of the list is.

After comments, here's an implementation that uses unique_ptr. Comments inline.

You will see that I have dropped the `last` pointer as it's not required. If you want 2-way linkage then use a ptr_type for the forward pointer and an observer_type for the back-link.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

const int SIZE=7;


// create the concept of an observer-only deleter
struct observer_only {
    template<class Any>
    void operator()(Any*) const noexcept {
        // nop
    }
};

// abstract the pointer type so we can change it if we don't like it
template<class Node> using ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<Node>;

// create the concept of an observer-only pointer
template<class Node> using observer_type = std::unique_ptr<Node, observer_only>;

// a means of converting a raw pointer to an observer
template<class Node> auto observe(Node* ptr) {
    return observer_type<Node>(ptr);
}

// a means of creating an observer to an owning pointer
template<class Node> auto observe(ptr_type<Node> const& ptr) {
    return observe(ptr.get());
}

struct Node {
    Node(int i)
            : val(i)
    {}

    // member function to add nodes provides logical encapsulation
    observer_type<Node> insert_after(ptr_type<Node>&& ptr) {
        assert(ptr.get());
        assert(ptr->next.get() == nullptr);
        ptr->next = std::move(this->next);
        this->next = std::move(ptr);
        return observe(this);
    }

    int val;
    ptr_type<Node> next = nullptr;
};

// node generator
ptr_type<Node> newNode(int v) { // Create and return new node
    ptr_type<Node> n(new Node(v));
    return n;
}

// print an observer
void print(observer_type <Node> o) { // Print the list
    for ( ; o.get() != nullptr ; o = observe(o->next))
    {
        std::cout << o->val << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// print a node
void print(ptr_type<Node> const& r) { // Print the list
    print(observe(r));
}

// test
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    auto root = newNode(rand());
    auto observer = observe(root);
    for (int i=1; i<SIZE; ++i) { // Build the list
        observer = observer->insert_after(newNode(rand()));
    }
    print(root);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Explanation of architectural approach

As requested in comments.

The the old days of assembler or C I'd have implemented a singly linked list (the second-simplest of all data structures) as merely a node containing a value and a pointer (address) to the next node. Of course we'd have to remember to destroy the node when removing it. We'd also have to remember whether a pointer "owned" (controlled the lifetime of) a node, or was merely an observer.

In modern c++, there are at least 2 enhancements available. First of course, we have RAII and smart pointers, so the destruction timing is always correct. Second, we can use types to indicate roles.

In the above code, I have two pointer types. One is an "owner" pointer and one is an "observer". These are both specialisations of unique_ptr in my code, but I could have written my own. However, using unique_ptr, I have some built in advantages:

1. a unique_ptr cannot be copied, so I cannot cause myself problems by accidentally sharing ownership.
2. even though the owning and non-owning pointers have different deleters (the observer's deleter is a no-op), they have the same interfaces. This makes generic programming easy.

In c++17, there is a template called `std::observer_ptr`, which is designed to perform the same role as my `observer_type`.

Now I can use the `owner_type` to handle the forward node linkages. This gives me clean RAII and firm ownership of nodes. It also mean that I can implement a `remove` function which returns the removed node pointer. I can then re-insert that node pointer into another list, or discard it (let it go out of scope). Either way, because it's controlled by an auto-deleting unique_ptr, the code will be correct. No leaks.

All operations on the list that do not affect lifetimes are done through an observer (there is a free function to create an observer from an owner). This provides both a visual cue to a maintainer, plus a compiler guarantee, that I won't accidentally mutate lifetimes when I am supposed to be observing or merely mutating the value held in the node.

#### fully linked list

OK, but how would I implement a linked list this way (i.e. with back-links as well as forward-links)?

We'd pick an 'owning' direction. Lets say forwards. Nodes would contain an `owner_type` pointing to and owning the next node, and an `observer_type` pointing to the previous node.

The list 'begin' pointer is an `owner_type`, the list's 'end' is an `observer_type`.

The Node would look something like this:

```
struct Node
{
    int value;  // my value type

    owner_type<Node>    next;   // pointer to the next node
    observer_type<Node> prev;   // observer of the previous node.
};
```

Inserting an removing nodes is the same as if they were raw pointers, it's just that we need to assign the pointers using `std::move`, because they're not copyable.

This is good, because it shows graphically in the code what we are trying to achieve. It forces us to spell out our intentions. If the code is later modified, it will be more difficult to introduce a logic error, because logically incorrect code won't compile.

Comment: Use case is on an interview where a linked list must be implemented--and ``std::forward_list`` is not acceptable. Traditionally, raw pointers were used to point to the next node in the list. In an effort to modernize the linked list implementation,  I'm trying to replace them with smart pointers.

Comment: The reason why I used shared_ptr is because I will use temporary pointers to nodes for various reasons: manipulating the list, reversing it, sorting, etc. ``std::unique_ptr`` will not work here, because there will be multiple pointers to the same node.

Comment: @kmiklas use std::unique_ptr and std::move to move them. You don't need shared_ptr. Linked list is the simplest data structure in the book. It's never needed reference counting.

Comment: if I use ``unique_ptr``, and need a pointer to a specific node in the list, I'm in trouble. Given the nature of singly-lists, where random access is not possible, this is common practice--and has come up twice on interviews. For example, let's say I want a temporary pointer to the 4th node. ``unique_ptr`` will not allow ``tmp = next`` (next of node 3, which points to node 4), because that would create shared ownership, which is not allowed. That's why I used ``shared_ptr``.

Comment: @kmiklas updated answer with a working example that uses unique_ptr.

Comment: Thank you. I spent some time reading your code, and I must admit that it's a bit of a stretch for me. I do understand that you're applying the observer pattern to a linked list, and using some C++14 concepts, but an explanation of the architectural approach that you took would really be helpful.

Comment: @kmiklas so done.